# How to benchmark frame-system on parachain?

Tags: benchmarking

After upgrading the Substrate to `polkadot-v0.9.43`.

I got the following error while running the runtime benchmarks.

```rs
2023-07-21 19:55:56 Starting benchmark: frame_system::set_code    
Error: Input("Benchmark frame_system::set_code failed: ValidationDataNotAvailable")
```

Before this upgrade, everything works well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that I missed an update on Cumulus/Substrate side.

```
- impl frame_system_benchmarking::Config for Runtime {}
+ impl frame_system_benchmarking::Config for Runtime {
+   fn setup_set_code_requirements(code: &sp_std::vec::Vec<u8>) -> Result<(), BenchmarkError> {
+       ParachainSystem::initialize_for_set_code_benchmark(code.len() as u32);
+       Ok(())
+   }
+ 
+   fn verify_set_code() {
+       System::assert_last_event(cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Event::<Runtime>::ValidationFunctionStored.into());
+   }
+ }
```

For more detail check, https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/2766.

---

The interesting thing is that this PR was not included in `polkadot-v0.9.43`. And I also found that cumulus didn't benchmark `frame-system` for `polkadot-v0.9.43`.